# vim how to simulate press of canc/delete key with norm command?

Tags: vim

With this line

```
:execute "normal! A;\<esc>D"
```

I do "normal" command wich permit to edit file without entering edit mode.
Then I add ; after line(A in edit mode) and the simulate ESC press key
and the I did D(delete after..in edit mode).
The question is..how to simulate del canc key?
I have tried  and  without success

For canc/delete I mean this key

[image]

Comment: What is "del canc key"?

Comment: Is this http://www.building-a-gaming-computer.com/images/Delete-key.jpg is called delete on english kb and canc(ella) on italian kb

Comment: Why do you need to simulate the Delete key? `x` in normal mode is typically more useful.

Comment: Because i have 30 lines and after the 30 lines another 30 lines,simulating the delete key with norm command i can add a caracther and the join the lines

Comment: You can join lines in normal mode with `J` or `gJ`. On a side note: it would be much easier if you could describe what you want to achieve, rather than describe the solution as you imagine it and have us coerce the actually useful information from you one bit at a time. Try to describe the problem, not the solution. :)

Comment: I know i can use J but i want to know how to simulate delete,maybe will be useful someday

Comment: It's `<Del>`, and it works the same way as `<Esc>`: `:exec "normal! \<Del>"`.

Comment: If you had as answer i can vote this for solution,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer, as requested.

As mentioned in `:h :normal`, you can represent special characters like this:

```
:execute "normal! \<key>"
```

`<key>` can be any of the keys listed at `:h keycodes`.  In your particular case, you want `<Del>`.